# FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Ivory\GoogleMap\Places\AutocompleteComponentRestriction' not found

Tags: google-maps, symfony, symfony-forms

I am using:

- symfony 2.3
- "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "~2.1"

I am trying to implement the example of [Autocomplete form type](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/tree/master/Resources/doc/usage/places), but I got the **FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Ivory\GoogleMap\Places\AutocompleteComponentRestriction' not found**. I checked if the class `AutocompleteComponentRestriction` does exit, but it was not the case.

So, which version of the bundle should I install?

Thanks

Comment: Did you register the bundle in your `AppKernel.php` file? Is the bundle correctly installed?

Comment: yes, I have registered it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

The problem is caused by the version I installed.

The problem is solved by selecting a more stable version:

```
{
    "require": {
    "egeloen/google-map": "~1.4@dev",
    "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "~2.2@dev"
    }
}
```